# When the build function really needed in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-widget

I'm totally new to flutter app but have strong concept in android/kotlin. I'm trying to understand the basic structure of the flutter app. I read that every widget need a `build` function to override to draw the children that was fine for me because in android/kotlin there is `onCreate();` or similar others. Then I saw this code on the official document page.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Center(
      child: Text(
        'Hello, world!',
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

It is working fine without `build()` function so what is the real purpose of the build function? And when we need it? What can be without it or what can't?

Comment: That *does* call the `build` methods of all the involved widgets.  You must implement a `build` method when you define a custom widget class.  You generally do not call it directly yourself.

Answer (score 1):

While you *could* have everything passed directly to `runApp`, it has a pretty big drawback:

Your app would be static. Without a `build` function (or a `builder` like with `FutureBuilder`), then your app will have no way of having dynamic content.

It is also pretty bad for reusability. You may want to extract some part of this widget tree into custom widgets, to reuse them in different locations – which implies a `build` method for that custom widget.

Comment: That's make sense, can you explain little more about `your app would be static`? How?

Comment: Because there's no mean to rebuild a part of your app with something different. You need a function at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter functions rather differently from many other platforms, and the name `build()` only adds to the confusion. :-)) To understand it, try to forget your previous experiences with other platforms temporarily.

#### Build() is really more like display()

Flutter uses the `build()` system to *display* the current frame. If the app has rapidly changing content, like an animation or a game, `build()` will be called 60 or more times per second, that is, for **every single frame.** Yes, that's the intention: no matter what its name is, think about it as a function to `displayCurrentFrame()`, not what the name might imply, to build a widget and then use it for the rest of the life of your app.

The system is perfectly optimized to know when it has to call `build()`. For content that doesn't change that often, it will not call it 60 times per second, it's smart enough not to do that. But every time it's really needed, it will be called (and for really complicated cases, you also have mechanisms to help Flutter decide when to call and what to call, to make sure that only parts that really change get redrawn, making it possible to avoid jerkyness in apps that really need rapidly changing content, mostly games).

The task of your `build()` is to take whatever data you currently have (that's called the *state* of your widget) and build up the widget (or widgets) just with that data, just for that single display frame. Next time around, with possibly different data, you will build it again and again.

So, a Flutter app works differently from many other platforms. You don't write code that waits for interaction from the user, then, for instance, calls a display function to show a new selection, a new text entry, a new image, anything directly. All your widgets function like this: whenever there is a change, the user does something, a response arrives from a call you made over the internet, a timer has elapsed, so basically, *anything* happens, your widget stores whatever new data you just received into its own state and tells Flutter that "hey, there are changes, please, call me so that I can draw a current version of myself." And Flutter will call its `build()` all right, and your widget will display itself according to this current new data. Again and again, as long as your app is alive and kicking.

At first, all this might seem like a waste of resources. Why rebuild everything on potentially every frame, instead of building a widget, keeping it alive and using it while the app lasts? The only realistic answer is: don't worry. The system was conceived explicitely with that structure in mind, it gets compiled into optimized code that works just fine, it's fast and responsive. Those widgets are lightweight enough so that this doesn't mean the slightest problem in real life (and, as already mentioned, in really complex programs where it starts to matter, you can have your say in how it should work, but you don't have to worry about that, either, until you reach that stage when it really counts). Just get used to it and accept that this is the way Flutter works. :-)

#### Other implications

All this has other implications as well. You should never do anything in `build()` that you're not comfortable doing on every display cycle: both because it shouldn't take too much time and because it will be called over and over again. Especially not anything that's a longish operation. You may *start* an async operation (actually, you probably do so quite often when acting on some user input), but that's async, it goes away to do its job and simply returns later. When it does return, you store the new data in the state, as described above, and use that in `build()` the next time around. But you never wait for anything there, or do any real complex programming logic and perform tasks there. It's nothing more than a `display()`, really.